# CRUD - Delete on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am stuck on my button "delete" when I try to delete a recording nothing happens.

In my **StudentController** I have that:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $student = Student::find($id);
        $student->delete();
        return redirect()->route('student.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Deleted successfully');
    }
```

And in my **index.blade.php** I have that:

```
@section('content')
  <div class="px-content">
    <div class="page-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-xs-center text-md-left text-nowrap">
          <h1><i class="px-nav-icon ion-android-apps"></i>List </h1>
        </div>
        <hr class="page-wide-block visible-xs visible-sm">
        <!-- Spacer -->
        <div class="m-b-2 visible-xs visible-sm clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{ route('student.create') }}">Create</a>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach($students as $student)
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$student->firstname}}</td>
                   <td> {{$student->lastname}} </td>
                   <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('student.edit',$student->id)}}">Edit</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{!! $students->links() !!}
  </div>
@endsection
```

For the folder **route**

```
Auth::routes();
route::resource('student','AdminController');
Route::PATCH('/update/{id}','AdminController@update');
```

I don't understand where is the problem ? I would like to know my error because I don't have of error message in fact.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show your route?

Comment: @ Web Artisan: yes of course, I edited my post

Comment: `route::resource` should probably be `Route::resource`; some servers are case-insensitive, but others are not, but either way, be consistent. Also, `Route::PATCH` to `Route::patch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the form so surround your button with a form tag like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('student.destroy', $student) }} ">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```